# Существует ли слово "обсценты" в русском языке?

Tags: лексика

Встречается выражение "обсценная лексика", а существует ли слово "обсценты", если да, что оно конкретно обозначает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если Вы ищете существительное, то это [обсценность](https://lopatin.academic.ru/83127/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) (синонимы: 
бесстыдность, матерность, ненормативность, непристойность).

В англ. *obscene* - adj., ему соответствует рус. *обсценный*.
*obscenity* - n.,  ему соответствует рус. *обсценность*.

Comment: Спасибо за углубление в тему. Просмотрел OALD, OLD, MerriamWebster, Collins. В русск. это, несомненно, научные термины. В англ. obscene/obscenity, кажется, вполне нейтральные слова (чуть заумные, но понятные образованному speaker'у) Пример из OLD: the men scowled and muttered obscenities - вполне нейтралный контекст (https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/obscenity). Обсценизм (thanks @slava1947) - понятно любому, кто интересуется лингвистикой (хотя в других лингв. словарях пока не нашел, если поискать, думаю, что-то еще можно найти). Думаю, "обсценная лексика" очень ходовой термин.

Comment: + еще в качестве комментария. Словари Oxford очень настаивают, что obscene имеют отношение к sexual matters. Но остальные словари так не настаивают, напр. Collins говорит о "accepted standards of decency or modesty".

Answer (score 3):

Есть другое слово...

ОБСЦЕНИЗМ (лат. ... — неприличный, зазорный) — непристойное выражение, бранное слово, ругательство...

См. [https://books.google.ru/books?id=pr3lAAAAMAAJ&q=%22обсценизм%22&dq=%22обсценизм%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjDtLnetprfAhWEAhAIHThXBvQQ6AEISzAI](https://books.google.ru/books?id=pr3lAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%22&dq=%22%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjDtLnetprfAhWEAhAIHThXBvQQ6AEISzAI)

Answer (score 2):

Смотрим в толковый словарь.

ОБСЦЕННЫЙ, -ая, -ое. [от лат. obscēnus - отвратительный, непристойный] Лингв. Оскорбительный, бранный

(Большой толковый словарь Кузнецова)

Так что слова "обсценты" в русском языке нет.

Comment: в качестве комментария. В англ. obscene - adj., obscenity - n. Возможно, кто-то это переносит в русский. Уже стал замечать, что некоторые люди могут лучше знать какое-то правило в англ., чем в русск. - o tempora, o mores)

Comment: @alexsms См. мой ответ.